# How to GET request into json data file

Tags: php, json

I want to load data in a json file with an html GET request:

```
http://www.example.com/xxx/?id={device}&time={time}&snr={snr}&station={station}&lat={lat}&lng={lng}&rssi={rssi}&data={data}&avgSnr={avgSnr}
```

On the server side is this my index.html file:

```html
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Demo Model</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php
     $_id = $_GET["id"];
     $_time = $_GET["time"];
     $_snr = $_GET["snr"];
     $_station = $_GET["station"];
     $_lat = $_GET["lat"];
     $_lng = $_GET["lng"];
     $_rssi = $_GET["rssi"];
     $_data = $_GET["data"];
     $_avgSnr = $_GET["avgSnr"];

     if ( $fl = fopen('data.json','a')) {
       fwrite($fl,"\"data\": { \"id\" : \"". $_id . "\", "
                             ."\"data\" :\"" . $_data . "\", "
                             ."\"from\" :\"" . $_station . "\", "
                             ."\"lat\" :\"" . $_lat . "\", "
                             ."\"lng\" :\"" . $_lng . "\" }\n" );
       fclose($fl);
     }
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

The data.json file stays empty, can someone explain me why?

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the inital code of @Farkie. You may also want to sanitize and verify that all the _GET indexes are set, if not throw a default value in for them as well.

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'id'     => $_GET['id'],
    'time'   => $_GET['time'],
    'snr'    => $_GET['snr'],
    'from'   => $_GET['station'],
    'lat'    => $_GET['lat'],
    'lng'    => $_GET['lng'],
    'rssi'   => $_GET['rssi'],
    'data'   => $_GET['data'],
    'avgSnr' => $_GET['avgSnr'],
);

if( $fl = fopen( 'data.json', 'a+' ) ){
    $stats = fstat( $fl );
    if( $stats['size'] ){
        $contents = fread( $fl, $stats['size'] );
        $collection = @json_decode( $contents, true );
        $collection = isset( $collection['data'] ) && is_array( $collection['data'] )
            ? $collection
            : array( 'data' => array() );
    } else {
        $collection = array( 'data' => array() );
    }
    $collection['data'][] = $data;
    ftruncate( $fl, 0 );
    fwrite( $fl, json_encode( $collection ) );
    fclose( $fl );
} else {
    echo 'Cannot open file';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're manually compiling JSON, which is just asking for trouble. Use `json_encode` and it'll do the lot for you:

```
<?php
$data = [
  'data' => [
    'id' => $_GET['id'],
    'data' => $_GET['data'],
    'from' => $_GET['station'],
    'lat' => $_GET['lat'],
    'lng' => $_GET['lng']
  ]
];

     if ( $fl = fopen('data.json','a')) {
       fwrite($fl, json_encode($data));
       fclose($fl);
     } else {
       echo 'Cannot open file';
     }
?>
```

Comment: Changed the code and tested with URL http://www.example.com/?id={device}&data={data}&station={station}&lat={lat}&lng={lng}

Comment: But there is no information posted in the json data file

Comment: Edited the answer. You might have problems with permissions writing to that file.

Comment: Check you permissions for the current directory you're in. Also please note that if you want to use this file as a collection of data's it won't work. You will basiclly have something like this repeating: {"data":{"id":"{device}","data":"{data}","from":"{station}","lat":"{lat}","lng":"{lng}"}}{"data":{"id":"{device}","data":"{data}","from":"{station}","lat":"{lat}","lng":"{lng}"}}

Comment: technically you could, separating on newline or something, but it's still awkward

Comment: Yes want to collect the data in a json file to view the device id's and values in an IOT project, is this not a good solution?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but then you don't need to use the data key, just the object of data itself. You have 3 options, use mysql, use sqlite or read the file into an json object then append to the data, after that write it as a whole